# Why do I need a semicolon here?

Tags: go

Here is a test Go program:

```
package main
import fmt "fmt"
func main () {
    ex := "moo cow\n";
    fmt.Print (ex)
}
```

With the semicolon, it compiles. However, if the semicolon is removed, it doesn't:

```
string.go:5: syntax error near fmt
```

Any ideas?

---

**Update (March 2012)**: Newer Go releases are able to compile both forms (with and without the semicolon).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Statements):

> Elements of a list of statements are
>   separated by semicolons, which may be
>   omitted only if the previous
>   statement:
>
> - ends with the closing parenthesis ")" of a list of declarations; or
> - ends with a closing brace "}" that is not part of an expression.

Comment: Yeah, seems like an issue of how it parses the text. I'd probably end up putting in all the semi-colons myself anyway. Unless it's not allowed. Haven't used it enough to know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer's technically here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#semicolons, but it's not very clear. It looks like you can leave semicolons off the end of statements, but not expressions. I think (I'm not certain here) that expressions are anything with an "=" (or ":=") in them (although += seems to be fine in the tutorial?)

Comment: After reading that, it sounds like you use them to separate statements in blocks, the way you do in Pascal. Outside of blocks, you don't need them.

Comment: Great answer +1. I quoted you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64381507/12817546.