# golang - Why ++ and -- not work in expressions?

Tags: go

What we take for granted in other languages and almost expect it to work in go, won't work - its almost so natural to do this, so why isn't the compiler happy? Just feeling like bailing out of go sometimes.

The only way to increment the value is to put it in its own separate line?

http://play.golang.org/p/_UnpZVSN9n

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    a := 1
    //Evaluate expression and pass into function - won't work
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(a++))
    //Braces around a++ also won't work
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa((a++)))
}
```

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`++` and `--` are statements in golang, not expressions

Comment: Royal pain! I've used prefix/postfix everywhere before and a ton of people out there are used to it. I don't see any confusion on something that people have been accustomed to for decades.

Comment: From the FAQ (linked by @ismail-badawi above): "As for postfix vs. prefix, either would work fine but the postfix version is more traditional; insistence on prefix arose with the STL, a library for a language whose name contains, ironically, a postfix increment."

Comment: If something is only okay because most developers are used to it, then its not okay. A new developer should not have to learn decades of cruft to catch up.

Comment: @semi Honestly, if that's the argument, they better just drop ++ and -- altogether. The current shape doesn't do much better to new developers, and is definitely a pain for old dogs.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, `++` and `--` are statements because it can be very difficult to understand the order of evaluation when they're in an expression.

Consider the following:

```
// This is not valid Go!
x := 1
x = x++ + x
y := 1
y = ++y + y
```

What would you expect `x` to be?  What would you expect `y` to be?  By contrast, the order of evaluation is very clear when this is a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help clarify, an expression has a `=`, `:=` or `+=` in them. A statement (such as `++` and `—`) does not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720029/12817546.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x int

func f(x int) {
    x = x + 1      //expression
    x++            //statement
    fmt.Println(x) //2
}

func main() {
    f(x) //expression statement
}
```

An "expression" specifies the computation of a value by applying operators and functions to operands. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions.

A "statement" controls execution. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Statements.

An "expression statement" is a function and method call or receive operation that appears in a statement. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_statements.